# Backwards/Forwards compatibility with C# .NET framework

Tags: c#, .net

I am looking into learning C# and can't seem to find a correct answer regarding which versions are backwards/forwards compatible.

1. If I write something in .NET 2.0 - will it be compatible with everything up to the latest version?
2. If I write something in 4.5 - Can I include files to allow it to run on a machine with .NET 2.0 installed?

I am trying to find which version of the .NET framework I should use to target the most amount of Windows machines. I would like my applications to work without requiring them to update the .NET version if it isn't necessary.

Comment: The earliest supported .NET version is 4.5.2. 2.0 is *NOT* supported - it came out 12 years ago. Are you confusing it with .NET Core perhaps?

Comment: As for compatiblity, there *are* many correct answers, starting from the docs themselves. The *do* explain what the breaking changes are from version to version. You won't find 12 year old documentation in the front page though.

Comment: Finally, the *world* has changed. Google, Github, banks, airlines and a *lot* of sites and services demand TLS1.2 which was added in .NET 4.5. NuGet packages are developed and tested for 4.5+. You may not be able to find any libraries or connect to services if you target 2.0

Comment: As for which version to use to target most machines, it's .NET Core 2.0 which runs on Linux. If it's only Windows machines, the latest full framework, 4.7.1

Comment: Microsoft cares a lot about backwards compatibility, there is no such thing as forward compatibility.  Time machines are for books and the movies.  So yes on 1 and no on 2.  You always favor targeting the framework version that your users have on their machine and maintained by Windows Update.  Currently 4.6.2 afaik.  It generally takes 6 months between release and general WU deployment, ymmv.